# cant seem to get this procedure to print outut in bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, git-bash

So when I run this on sublime ctrl-b I get the following output:

```
2
this is a example string with a _x_
ok so you have 3 left
What is your guess?
```

However when I run this in git-bash it simply runs, no errors, no output, no request for user input. I am new at this, and this is just a small part of a school quiz I am doing. Any suggestions?

```
string1 = "this is a example string with a _x_"
sample_list = [1, 2, 3]

def main():
    print (sample_list[1])
    print (string1)
    chances = 3
    while chances > 0:
        print ("ok so you have " + str(chances) + " left")
        answer = input("What is your guess?")
        if answer == sample_list[0]:
            print ("Great, here is your new string!")
            print (string1.replace('_x_', str(sample_list[1])))
        elif answer != sample_list[1]:
            print ("Aw Schucks")
        chances -= 1
    print ("Out of chances")

main()
```

Comment: How are you running it in git bash? I'm not super familiar but I don't believe git bash has a python environment

Comment: yeah the class had us set it up and it works on many other things I have written. The command line is winpty python <yourFileName>